# Password to ssh connec to termux

Tags: termux

I tried to test ssh on termux  which prompt of the password

[image]

At temp my screen lock number but failed.

What's the password?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `passwd` command to manually set one.

When invoked dirently, it doesn't ask you for your previous password and just sets a new one:

```
~ $ passwd
New password:
Retype new password:
New password was successfully set.
~ $
```

The you can SSH into Termux using this password.

However, I recommend using an SSH key after you're all set.

Comment: In order to work you have to install `openssh`.